# How to handle Remove operation for a portlet with use-default-template=false?

Tags: liferay, customization, portlet

I have a portlet with my own template and which has `<use-default-template>false</use-default-template>` in it's config.

What if I wish to make my own button to remove my portlet from a page? How to handle remove operation? What URL to query? How to know if current user has permission to remove portlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to remove portlet from javascript, if so

```
Liferay.Portlet.close(jQuery('#p_p_id_' + my_portlet_id + '_').get(0), true, {});
```

or

```
Liferay.Portlet.close(document.getElementById('p_p_id_' + my_portlet_id + '_'), true, {});
```

where second parameter is skipConfirm. Take a look at /ROOT/html/js/liferayportlet.js

In your template you could test for whether to show close button/icon with

```
#if ($portletDisplay.isShowCloseIcon())
   ...
#end
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! As I understood, first 2 samples is javascript. Where to learn the API of these objects? And in what language is the second?

Comment: Second is Velocity, if you need java let me know. For java script you should go trough javascript files from "[war_instalation_folder]/ROOT/html/js" directory of Liferay instalation or "portal-web/docroot/html/js" directory of Liferay source